# Having trouble deploying a node express app

Tags: express, deployment, local

I have remote windows 11 machine where I am trying to deploy my simple node express app. It has currently one default route that serves an index.html. The app works well on my dev machine locally (surprise!). I followed the below steps to install it on this brand new windows machine:

1. Open a cmd window in admin mode
2. Installed node and non
3. Created a folder ‘xyz’ for the app.js etc
4. Copied app.js, package.json and index.html there
5. Installed express by non install express and that ran successfully.
6. Trying to start the server with ‘npm start’ from the cmd window.
7. I get an error when the script encounters require(‘express’), saying it is not found.

I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

I tried following the instructions for installing express on a local machine and expecting the app should start up.

Comment: What is `non install express`?  Do you mean `npm install express`?  It sounds like perhaps express is not installed in the right directory.

Comment: My bad - it's a typo. npm install express - is what I wanted to say. Also, I made sure I am in the application folder before I issued the command

Comment: Then, show us the EXACT error message you get.  Perhaps add a screenshot of the command shell to the end of your question.  The error seems to be saying that Express isn't in the right place.  But, it's also possible that `package.json` is doing something different than you expect when you try to start with `npm start`.  Did you try starting things with `node app.js` with the current directory set to where `app.js` is?

Comment: Ok. I got it working now. Here is what I have done:   1) npm uninstall express; 2) npm install -g express; 3) npm link express

Comment: That just means you weren't installing Express in the right place and how that you installed it globally, it can be found there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.